# PHP Codeigniter - passing variables using action in form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass a variable to Controller, but can't. The form I am submitting works fine, it shows everything. But when I try to *delete* a row, then the problem is that I can't submit it, so that my action would look like */Products/delete/2*.

See my code below:

```
<tbody>
  <?php
    for($i = 0; $i < count($all); $i++){?>
      <tr>
        <form action="/Products/delete/<?= $i ?>" method="post">
          <td><input name="name" value="<?php echo $all[$i]['name'] ?>" readonly></td>
          <td><input name="price" value="<?php echo $all[$i]['price'] ?>" readonly></td>
          <td><input name="qty" value="<?php echo $all[$i]['qty'] ?>" readonly></td>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
        </form>
      </tr>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Usually you'd use the full URL or `<?=base_url();?>`. Are you getting any errors and if so what are they?

Comment: what was the error you getting?

Comment: Why you are creating forms for every row. You can delete with `<a href='<?php base_url(); ?>products/delete/<?php $i; ?>>Delete</a>`. Also the ID of Deleting, need to be from DB, not from $i (wich returns numbers from 1 to n.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Saving the name price qty? Or Delete the row? Post your controller source code also.

Comment: I don't get an error. I should see it like as I said, e.g. /Products/delete/2. I am creating forms, because I have to include button to delete.

Comment: I suggest to be more clear on question. Edit and tell us more what do you want exactly.

Comment: For checking errors. Try `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Erman, I will create the controller method later, because for now I need to pass the variable, that's it, e.g.  localhost/Products/delete/2.

Comment: try with <?php base_url(); ?>index.php/products/delete/<?php $i; ?> path

Comment: Erman, the code you gave is working partially, but it doesn't take the parameter, so it becomes /Products/delete. That's it. It doesn't take the final $i parameter.

Comment: saty, I tried this, but final $i parameter is not getting added, please see my previous response to Erman.

Comment: <a href='<?php echo site_url('products/delete/' . $i); ?>>Delete</a>

Comment: Nurgul Alshyn, change to `<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Products/delete/<?php echo $i; ?>" method="post">` and test it.

Comment: Sorry, mine should be site_url() instead of base_url()

Comment: Craig, your first comment worked. Thanks a lot! Thanks other as well for help!

Comment: You're welcome, although all I did was add the "echo" to @ErmanBelegu 's comment.

Comment: @Crag, maybe is fair for you to post the answer for the others how could have the same problem in future. Thanks